# Error with model.list() in OpenAI Python Library

Tags: python, powershell, openai-api

When attempting to use model.list(), the library encounters an authentication error due to the incorrect configuration of the API key. I've been continuously receiving the error message.

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "your_api_key"

models = openai.Model.list()

print(models.data[0].id)

chat_completion = openai.Completion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}]
  )

print(chat_completion.choices[0].message.content)`
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\gpt1.py", line 6, in <module>
    openai.Model.list()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\listable_api_resource.py", line 52, in list
    requestor, url = cls.__prepare_list_requestor(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\listable_api_resource.py", line 20, in __prepare_list_requestor
    requestor = api_requestor.APIRequestor(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 138, in __init__
    self.api_key = key or util.default_api_key()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\util.py", line 186, in default_api_key
    raise openai.error.AuthenticationError(
openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = <API-KEY>', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=<API-KEY>). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = <PATH>'. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the environmental variable, and try setting up authentication the same way they do for the models list [documenation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/list) using the OS environment [variable](https://analyzingalpha.com/openai-api-python-tutorial).

```
import os
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_KEY')
openai.api_key = api_key
```

Here are instructions[enter link description here](https://analyzingalpha.com/jupyter-notebook-environment-variables-tutorial) for setting environment variables.  This is for a juypter notebook, but it shouldnt be that much different from setting them or your own environment.